# Can electromagnetic waves energy increase by simply having more sources?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Not sure if this is a trivial question or not. But I am essentially asking is if for instance we have a phone that emits "x" amounts of frequency and is pointed towards like a cell. If I add 10 more phone does the cell now experience now 10 times as much frequency or is that not true?

Comment: Signal frequencies will not change, but intensity - will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signal strength of a phone is a measure of how much electromagnetic energy (of a particular range of frequency) is passing through it’s antenna. The frequency of the radiation is a fixed property of the emitter. What is changing is the amount of energy passing through. This scales with the number of emitters, provided they are all equidistant from the antenna.

It is to be noted that the strength falls of inversely with the square of the distance between the emitter and the antenna.

Comment: So how much does amount of energy change by exactly? (in terms of like some formula?)

Comment: @fp1234 $E_{\rm total} = E_1 + E_2 + E_3...$

Comment: The reason I am asking this is because I am doing a basic theoretical calculation of how many phones it would take to hit an electron off an atom or disrupt bonds. (like carbon-carbon or hydrogen bonds in DNA). Then does it makes sense that the sum of the energy can then have whatever effect after putting a large amount of phones towards some cells or are there some considerations/effects that would be worthy to take into account?

Comment: Now that is a different question altogether. If we are looking at it quantum mechanically, radiation is made up of photons and each photon has an energy proportional to the frequency ($\omega$) of the radiation wave (rather the other way round). So the total energy will be $N\hbar\omega$ where $N$ is the number of photons in the wave. Now the atoms will interact with this radiation if and only if there is a transition possible with exactly this energy. Otherwise the atoms won’t absorb.

Answer (score 0):

When you add more sources, you have more photons emitted, but each one has the same frequency and energy as with one source. Classicaly, you have an electromagnetic wave with the same frequency but larger amplitude (assuming the waves from various surces don't have a destructive interference).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. They need to be in phase at the receive point for coherence.

Comment: No, the energy is proportional to the number of phones when their phases are not coherent.